# Div taking up half the height and width of the body

Tags: css, reactjs

I need to make a site that looks like this one: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bvV7UFjC_lg6QdNeTK7Er_chQqwfPmny/view?usp=sharing
Right now it sort of looks like that one, but the first div (the one with the background image) doesn´t take up half the height and width of the viewport. Any ideas on how I could fix it?

Screenshot: [image]

HTML:

```
<div id="main-menu">
        <p id="invitation_title">
          Escapate a
          </p>
        <p id="city_title">Nueva York</p>
        <Menu />
        <FlightSelector />

      </div>
```

CSS

```
#main-menu{
  text-align:center;
  background-image: url('http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/new-york-background-image.jpg');
  background-position: center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: where you specified that *half the height*?

Comment: I set both width and height at 100%, but right now it isn´t even taking up the whole body.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. Do you want it to take up half the viewport height or entire viewport?

Comment: 100% of what. Maybe your `main-menu` is in another `div` with that height. Show your complete html

Comment: Ideally, I will add a chart that will take half the screen while this div takes the other half. But right now, for some reason, it´s taking less than a third.

Comment: Should have mentioned it´s React

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background image to take the entire page, you can set the height in terms of viewport like so:

```
#main-menu {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Here’s a link that explains more about viewports:

https://tutorialzine.com/2015/05/simplify-your-stylesheets-with-the-magical-css-viewport-units

Comment: Doing this, but still no dice: body{
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}  #main-menu{
  text-align:center;
  background-image: url('http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/new-york-background-image.jpg');
  background-position: center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 overflow: auto;
}